# accessing multiple properties of a php object

Tags: php, class, object

I am delving into the OOP world and I understand the concepts.  In the below code, How would I make it so I can access each attribute of the user object?  for example, I would want to show user's lastName I would do echo $user->lastName;.   right now, im stuck with only getting 1 attribute of the object.(in this example, address)  I may be waaaaay off here, as this is my first attempt. I have been reading on how to do this stuff and I feel like Im missing something....

```
  class user
 {

    public $firstName = "Bob";
    public $lastName = "Jones";
    public $address = "1234 Anywhere Street";
    public function userInfo()
    {
            return $this->address;
    }
 }       

    $user = new user();
    echo $user->userInfo();
```

Comment: Since you made all of the member variables of `user` public you can access each of them directly by doing `$user->varname` where `varname` is the name one of the member variables.

Comment: so i dont even need the function userInfo?

Comment: Nope, in this case it's unnecessary. Had you made the member variables private or protected then you would need `getter` functions to retrieve the member variables and `setter` functions to set the member variables.

Comment: awesome. from what i read, i want public when i want other things to be able to access these vars, and private when its only for this class.  is it a similar concept as globals?

Comment: Has nothing to do with globals. It is just an access policy for variables inside this class. Globals are global and available anywhere. As a general rule, foget about globals and never ever use them anywhere. It's bad practice and a security flaw ;)

Comment: If you are experienced with this property stuff and want getter/setters but dont want to write one for each of your variables, you can also check out magic functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get but one step at a time! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting reads for someone starting to work with basic OOP in PHP:

- Basic OOP http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
- Properties http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php
- Constructors http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
- Inheritance http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php
- Magic Methods http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

There are also fine OOP tutorials for PHP out there. This is just one of the top Google hits:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/